# How to pass parameters to C# Console Application via task scheduler on win 2k3 server?

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, console-application

I have researched around the web and have found no answer to this simple question.  I know on new versions of windows task scheduler that it actually has an option area for parameters but on win2k3 there is no such option.

I am assuming that I just need to pass it as part of the path of the .exe.

Something like. :

```
"c:\myProgram.exe boolParam=false;stringParam='myVal'"
```

I am almost positive that this can be done in either the stated way above or something very similar but my syntax is apparently way off and I have tried several variations with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you just try this?

```
"c:\myProgram.exe false myVal"
```

Comment: You answered first, so giving it to you.  My real issue was .net framework 4.0 was not installed.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. The question is exactly what I'm looking for but NOT the answer. Where is the Task Name? e.g. schtasks.exe  /RUN /TN "taskName"  args

Comment: It's possible that some of the tricks I used in here might help: https://github.com/TomChantler/Always-Admin-VS (I promise that URL won't ever change unless GitHub goes bust) :-)

Answer (score 3):

Like this

> `"c:\myProgram.exe false myVal"`

You will need to parse false it will come in as a **string** not a **bool**